# Having Trouble manipulating code to creat a mountain image

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, windows64

This is my code so far but it only makes on half of the mountain image out of the *'s I'm trying to go for

How do I mirror the code or change it so that it creates that same mountain side, but on the left side as well?

It should look something like this: `/\`

```
size = 5

for row in range(0, size+5):
    for columnSpc in range(size+row):
        print('*', end='')

for columnStar in range(row+row):
    print('*', end='')

print()
```

Comment: Please reformat your question, it's hurting my eyes

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
size = 5

for row in range(1, size+1):
    for space in range(size-row+1, 0, -1):
        print(' ',end='')
    for star in range(1,row*2):
        print('*',end='')
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

Comment: Given from the “/\” in the OP I assume you need to rotate the pyramid by 90° counter-clockwise.

Comment: @xZise he can rotate the screen ;)

Comment: @xZise done. edited answer to make it couter-clockwise

Comment: Wow thanks a bunch this was bugging me for a while. And it was only a practice problem too lol. Looks exactly like its suppose to thank you.

Comment: @A.M it is not the answer you are looking for?